# Sharepoint lockout

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

Recently a guy from our 3rd line team thought it would be funny to delete my account from AD. This has now been re-added. Everything is back to normal apart from my Access to Sharepoint sites. 
I am getting `The file exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070050)` Error on all sites.

After some googleing I came across a guy with the same issue and it was an issue with the SID being different from my old account. Since this I deleted my account from Site Administrators and re-added. This would refresh the SID with the new one. I also check on the Content database that the site ID matched using the following transactions and the SIDs match.

```
select s.Id, w.FullUrl from Sites s inner join Webs w on
s.RootWebId = w.Id

select * from UserInfo where tp_Login='domain\username' and
tp_SiteID='<ID Code>'
```

I am now a bit clueless.

Comment: The new account has a new SID, so it has no connection with the old account.  You'll need to remove the old one and grant whatever rights you need to the new one just as if you were a new hire.

Comment: Is this not done where I deleted it from the Site Collection Admins and then re-added?

Comment: Your user account was removed from the Site Collection Admin group. However the account itself remained. You need to explicitly remove the user account from the list of users

Comment: Ok i think i get it now. Delete account from Site Collection Group then delete from list of users, Add back in to list of users the back in as Site Collection Group? 

Also I take it by list of users you mean where I will be added in the Groups list? 

Thanks

Comment: OK So this still hasent given me access. Do i have to go to each individual site and delete the account from Site Collection administrators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now deleted the user account from Site Colection from Central Admin and also deleted from Site Collection from all the seperate sites. Performed a IISreset and then re-added the user account to Site Colection in Cental Admin and onto all sites. I have now got all my access rights back.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used the command:

stsadm -o migrateuser ...

To copy your old rights into your new account.